# Calculating sum matrix with in Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a custom class MW. MW gets 2 matrices-(ke matrix and val matrix).

And I am trying to sumup all the matrices coming into reducer.

So I need to first parse my string and I stored them into 2 double array.
I am geting all the ke matrix and val matrix in reducer.

But I am not able to sumup.

Any suggestion.

Inorder to get the sum outside the forloop,i declared them as static.

```
public class Reducer  extends
Reducer<IntWritable, MW, Text, Text> {  
    static double[][] key;
    static double[][] value;
    public void reduce(IntWritable  keys,
            Iterable<MW> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    for (MW c : values)
    {
        String data = c.toString();
        data = data.trim();
        String[] parts = data.split("#");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
        /*
         * Parse key
         */
        String[] keyrows = part1.split(",");

        String[][] keymatrix = new String[keyrows.length][]; 
        int keyr = 0;
        for (String keyrow : keyrows) {
            keymatrix[keyr++] = keyrow.split("\\|");
        }


       double[][] ke = new double[keymatrix.length][keymatrix[0].length];
       for (int i = 0; i<keymatrix.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j<keymatrix[0].length; j++) {
               ke[i][j] = Double.valueOf(keymatrix[i][j]);
        }
       }
      key = new double[ke.length][ke[0].length];

       for(int sumi = 0;sumi<ke.length;sumi++){
           for(int sumj=0;sumj<ke[0].length;sumj++){
               key[sumi][sumj] += ke[sumi][sumj];
           }
       }
    /*Parsing  value
    */      
    String[] valuerows = part2.split(",");

        String[][] valuematrix = new String[valuerows.length][]; 
        int valr = 0;
        for (String valuerow : valuerows) {
            valuematrix[valr++] = valuerow.split("\\|");
        }


       double[][] val = new double[valuematrix.length][valuematrix[0].length];
       for (int i = 0; i<valuematrix.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j<valuematrix[0].length; j++) {
       val[i][j] = Double.valueOf(valuematrix[i][j]);
        }

       }



       //calculating sum for value
        value = new double[val.length][val[0].length];

       for(int sumi = 0;sumi<val.length;sumi++){
           for(int sumj=0;sumj<val[0].length;sumj++){
               value[sumi][sumj] += val[sumi][sumj];
           }
       }
                   }


System.out.println("sum 1");
        for(int diai=0;diai<key.length;diai++){
            for(int diaj=0;diaj<key[0].length;diaj++){
                System.out.print(key[diai][diaj]+"\t");

            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
    System.out.println("sum 2");
        for(int diai=0;diai<value.length;diai++){
            for(int diaj=0;diaj<value[0].length;diaj++){
                System.out.print(value[diai][diaj]+"\t");

            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
```

**UPDATE**
I think the problem is with in line

```
 key = new double[ke.length][ke[0].length];
```

and

```
value = new double[val.length][val[0].length];
```

before summing I am rebuilding the matrix key and value inside the loop.

It should build it once before the loop and then add to it. 
But to do that I should do

```
double[][] key = new double[ke.length][ke[0].length];
double[][] value = new double[val.length][val[0].length];
```

before

```
for (MW c : values)
    {
```

but
How will I get the `dimensions` outside the for loop?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about your key and values to reducer. So for each key matrix are you passing a list of value matrix??

Comment: actually i am not using a key in reducer. it is a dummy value.i need only the values from mapper. and the value is 2 matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i solved the problem .

i emitted the `dimensions` as key to reducer. It worked.